# ML6 Type Coordinate Complexes - Drawing a Molecular Energy Orbital Diagram

Tags: inorganic-chemistry, coordination-compounds, transition-metals

In class we recently discussed how to draw out molecular orbital energy diagrams for compounds such as NH3 (ammonia). Building upon this, we touched on how to construct a molecular energy diagram for ML6 type coordinate complexes, namely [Cr[NH3]6)3+. I am confused as to where to begin our diagram formation. All I know right now is that we consider that NH3 coordinates to Cr through it's a1 HOMO. I don't know how to proceed beyond this.

Comment: Have you tried looking in a textbook? Because of the importance of octahedral complexes, all inorganic texts devote a fair amount of space to construction of MO diagrams for ML6 complexes.

Comment: Unfortunately our prof doesn't have a textbook for us in this class. We're only left to our handwritten notes.

Comment: Look in a library? There is a list here: https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/q/37303/16683

Comment: @Henro You can literally open any textbook about inorganic chemistry...